# rails3 setting a variable in a model using ajax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, jquery, variables, model

I'm new to rails, and unable to set a variable in my modal using ajax! My approach is; I first pass it from external javascript (jquery dialog) to my controller, then to my model method as a parameter. Please critique!

My javascript (ajax within jquery-dialog button):

```
click: function() {
    var qtySelected = $("#quantity[data-id='" + prodvarid + "'] input").val();//inputValue check
    qtySelected = parseInt(qtySelected); //ensure value is int
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '/line_items',
        beforeSend: function(xhr){
             xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'))},
        data: {product_id: prodvarid, qty_selected: qtySelected, remote: true},
        dataType: "script"
    });
    alert("input value is: " + qtySelected); //inputValue check
    $("#quantity[data-id='" + prodvarid + "'] input").val(1); //reset default value on submit
    $(this).dialog("close");
}
```

My controller - it receives the :qty_selected value through an ajax POST, to which it is passed into my model using ctlQty:

```
# POST /line_items
# POST /line_items.json
def create
 @cart = current_cart
 product = Product.find(params[:product_id])
 ctlQty = :qty_selected
 @line_item = @cart.add_product(product.id, ctlQty)

 respond_to do |format|
 if @line_item.save
  format.html { redirect_to(store_index_url) }
  format.js   { @current_item = @line_item }
  format.json { render json: @line_item, status: :created, :location => @line_item }
  else
   format.html { render :action => "new" }
   format.json { render json: @line_item.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
 end
 end
```

My model receives the value and sets the local variable current_qty:

```
def add_product(product_id, qty_selected)

current_qty = qty_selected
if current_qty
    current_qty = qty_selected
else
    current_qty = 1
end

current_item = line_items.find_by_product_id(product_id)
if current_item
    current_item.quantity += current_qty
else
    current_item = line_items.build(:product_id => product_id)
end
current_item
end
```

Upon testing, I receive:

```
"TypeError (:qty_selected can't be coerced into Fixnum)"
app/models/cart.rb:17in '+'
app/models/cart.rb:17in 'add_product'
app/controllers/line_items_controller.rb:48in 'create'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message states that you're trying to use a symbol and a number. Indeed, in the controller, it should be:

```
ctlQty = params[:qty_selected].to_i   # instead of ctlQty = :qty_selected
```

Also, in `add_product`, the first 6 lines looks complex, and could simply be written

```
current_qty = qty_selected || 1
```

Comment: Awesome. With the addition of "+= current_qty.to_i" the error is gone, and the code works perfectly!